# Search order based on user's votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, search

For a while I've been thinking that the stackoverflow search is broken... It does not use my up/down votes on questions, making it very hard to find an answer that I already voted.
Basically, I up/down vote questions and answers for two reasons:

1. To improve the community by selecting the best questions and answers (benefits other users).
2. To be able to find a particular solution at some point in the future (benefits myself).

In reality, the second use case doesn't work, because when I search on the site, I don't get the up voted questions/answers prioritized, so the only way to look for a previous question is to go through them by hand...

I think it would be very useful, than when logged in, the search results are ordered having my own votes rank better than the communities, or some search option to only search in answers I actively participated (be it by up/down voting, commenting, or posting the question / answer).

What do you think? Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: If I want to remember something I favourite, bookmark or answer it... trying to find the needle in the haystack isn't made easier if you use a pitchfork instead of your hands - enough cliche :-)?